Accessing Google Drive APIs from AWS lambda
I created an app on google console (Oauth2) and when I run test java code from laptop, I am able to access GDrive files. Though it asks me to grant permission by opening a page in browser. Since this is not possible in AWS lambda, what is the way forward? I had created Desktop app.
I want to create a service account in google cloud console as I think that might work for me but it is totally not clear what permissions account will need. I found the below documentation page but it did not help
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-roles#:~:text=Each%20permission%20in%20the%20Google,For%20more%20information%2C%20see%20Views.

This might help: Google Drive API Authentication
